# Invalid Circles disappear, when Sub ends (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I want to **circle** Invalid Data like this:

[image: circle invalid data]

[image]

The circles should appear when a user saves the document, so I created this function:

```
Private Function clearInvalidCircles(sheetName)
    With Sheets(sheetName)
        .ClearCircles
        ShapesBefore = .Shapes.Count
        .CircleInvalid
        ShapesAfter = .Shapes.Count
        If ShapesAfter > ShapesBefore Then
            MsgBox "Invalid entries are marked with a red circle, please change it to a valid input."
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

... and added it to the `Workbook_BeforeSave` function:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    clearInvalidCircles "Sheet1"
End Sub
```

But if I want to save the document, it doesn't show the invalid data...

I debugged my code and found out, that `clearInvalidCircles` worked and the circles only disappeared when the document is saved (after `Workbook_BeforeSave`)

Is there a better option to avoid this problem?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers...

Comment: I suppose you could call your function on the `Workbook_AfterSave` and `Workbook_Open` events?

Comment: Why are you clearing all the circles before checking the amount invalid?

Comment: The circles remained when I placed your code in `AfterSave` instead of `BeforeSave`

Comment: @maxhob17 `Workbook_open` doesn't fit my needs. `Workbook_AfterSave` worked, I didn't know that such a function exist... Thanks!